# Network Drive Script for new users

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've never done anything like this before, but I have been asked to write a script to automatically map a network drive for new starters, and I'd like some help please!

I believe I can do this using a .bat file. It is for an external customer, but I can VPN onto their server. The script will hopefully prevent us from having to manually map drives every time. This will be done on a Windows environment, with most users either running 7 or 10. I need the drive to mapped permanently (i.e. the same as if I were to log on to their machine, C: Map Network Drive, etc.)

Below is a copy of the code I'm using at the moment:

```
`echo off 

net use s: /delete 

net use s: \\%Nimrod%\backups /persistent:y`
```

It runs, but there are no errors and the intended drive does not appear on my system. The drive is active and I can manually set it up.

Any ideas where I am going wrong please?

Comment: Do you have an environment variable in your system named `%Nimrod%`? _because you haven't set one in the script you have posted_.

Comment: I haven't. Nimrod is the name of the drive I'm trying to reach.

Comment: It should say Nimrod then, otherwise as an undefined variable it will read as `net use s: \\\backups /persistent:y`

Comment: Thank you. I'm now using {net use s: \Nimrod\Backups} and I'm now getting an error message. "Network connection could not be found C:\Path\echo off" The drive is up as I can ping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably suggest using this syntax:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Exist S:\ Net Use S: /Delete
Net Use S: \\1.1.1.1\Nimrod\backups /Persistent:Yes
```

Comment: I've been trying this, and i keep getting Error 53. I know the drive is available as my colleagues are all mapped to it, as well as being able to ping it.

Comment: I've fixed it!!! I needed to include the IP address of NAS as well as its name (Nimrod). The file path now reads s: \\1.1.1.1\Nimrod\Backups and it works. Thanks for all of your help and patience today. I appreciate it.

Comment: I have updated my answer to match your comment. _Please consider marking my answer as accepted._

Answer (score 0):

The above post from Compo has worked. The code is correct, but I needed to add the IP address of the NAS device as well. The code now reads:

```
@echo off
```

If Exist S:\ net use s: /delete

Net Use s: \IP address\FileName\FileName :Persistent:Yes

Thanks again Compo!